# How do I select all records with more than n child records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

For the situation where `Employee has_many Clients`, I am trying to write an ActiveRecord query that will return all of the Employees that have n or more clients. It's simple enough to write a join query to find all of the Employees with at least 1 client but extending my query to this more general case has left me stumped.

Edit - I should add that I'm trying to do this entirely at the database level. I want to avoid iterating over the collection in Ruby.

Comment: I also have the Squeel gem available to me if that helps

Comment: GROUP BY, HAVING, and COUNT are your friends. A bit of time with the [PostgreSQL docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/index.html) might help you figure out the SQL and then you can backtrack to the AR.

Comment: Will do mu. I think I need to bite the bullet and learn SQL properly. AR is very nice but it can shield me from more than is good for me. A job for tomorrow methinks.

Comment: A very worthwhile exercise (not that I've learned SQL properly but I do have a much better understanding of joins and aggregate functions). My answer below!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Thanks to mu and vijikumar, this is what I've come up with

```
Employee.select("employees.*").joins(:clients).group("employees.id").having("count(clients.id) > ?", n)
```

Comment: Not sure the part `.select("employees.*")` is necessary.

Answer (score 4):

```
@employees=Employee.select{|e|e.clients.length > n }
```

Active record query for the same..

```
@employees=Employee.find(:all, :joins=>"as emp inner join clients as c on c.employee_id=emp.id", :select=>"emp.id", :group=>'emp.id having count(c) > n')
```

it will give the employee id's who are all having more than n clients.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not an ActiveRecord query. Also, > not >=.

Comment: but it will give the expected result.

Answer (score -2):

try this,

```
@emp_client = []
@emp = Employee.all
@emp.each do |e|
  if @emp.clients.present?
    @emp_clinet << @emp
  end
end
```

Comment: `present?` only works for `n` being 0. You also misspelled `@emp_clinet`.